# factorise the expression: $\frac{1}{4}k^2(k+1)^2 + (k+1)^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

How to factorise this expression so that (A step-by-step method of attaining is welcomed):

$$\frac{1}{4}k^2(k+1)^2 + (k+1)^3$$

is equal to

$$\frac{1}{4}(k+1)^2(k+2)^2$$

I have tried:

$$\frac{k^2(k+1)^2}{4}+(k+1)^3$$

How do I go from $\frac{1}{4}k^2(k+1)^2$ to $\frac{1}{4}(k+1)^2$ and $(k+1)^3$ to $(k+2)^2$ ; what are the methods for this?

However I do not know how to get onto the next steps which are:

(1) $$(k+1)^2(\frac{k^2}{4}+k+1)$$
(2)$$(k+1)^2(\frac{k^2+4k+4}{4})$$

Comment: prove what by induction ?

Comment: Hint: $k^2+4k+4=(k+2)^2$. ... @AhmadBazzi The question is ... Guess what is being proved by induction.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit that one made my day !!

Comment: You're not doing any induction. You only want to factorise the first expression.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1}{4}k^2(k+1)^2 + (k+1)^3$$

$$\frac{1}{4}k^2(k+1)^2 + (k+1)(k+1)^2$$

$$\left[\dfrac14k^2+(k+1)\right](k+1)^2$$

$$=\dfrac{k^2+4k+4}4(k+1)^2?$$

$$=\frac{1}{4}(k+1)^2(k+2)^2$$

Comment: I cannot seem to reduce the $(k+1)^3$ into $(k+1)^2$; That is my main difficulty.

Comment: @Meilton:   did you understand that I factored out $(k+1)^2$ going from my first equation to my second?  $(k+1)^3=(k+1)(k+1)^2$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner How did you get $k^2+4k+4$ from $k^2+(k+1)$  wouldn't it be $$\frac{1*k^2+k+1}{4}$$?

Comment: @Meilton:  I got $\dfrac{k^2+4k+4}4$ from $\dfrac14(k+2)^2$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Do you mind showing me this with a simple step-by-step method?

Comment: @Meilton:  I edited accordingly